# How to cold boot emulator using command line(CMD)

Tags: android, react-native, cmd, android-emulator, adb

I am trying to open emulator without opening android studio every time while developing react-native.
Emulator can be opened using this lines of code.

```
cd C:\Users\<your_user_name>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
emulator -list-avds
emulator @<your_adb_name>
```

But now I want to `cold-boot` emulator some times to resolve `emulator not responding` issue using cmd. Any idea to solve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I am able to solve my this problem using `-no-snapshot-load` with emulator @<your_adb_name>

```
cd C:\Users\<your_user_name>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
emulator -list-avds
emulator @<your_adb_name> -no-snapshot-load
```

Answer (score 5):

On linux, if you add this to your `.bashrc`, when you call `avd-coldboot` (or whatever you decide to name it) you will get a list of AVDs to select from for cold-booting.

This should work regardless of how many AVDs you have set up

```sh
function avd-coldboot {
echo 'Choose Android AVD to cold-boot:'

select avd in $(emulator -list-avds);
do
  if [ -n "$avd" ]
  then
    echo "Cold-booting AVD '$avd'"
    emulator @$avd -no-snapshot-load
    break
  else
    echo "Unknown option: '$REPLY'"
  fi
done
}
```

Example terminal I/O

```
~/jnk$ avd-coldboot
1) Pixel_3a_API_30
2) Pixel_4_API_30
#? 1 
emulator: Android emulator version 30.7.5.0 (build_id 7491168) (CL:N/A)
```

Answer (score 0):

- reach to the folder where your sdk is install and go to emulator folder in it.
- open cmd from this folder.
- run this command `emulator -list-avds` to get installed avds.
- For run the avd with cold boot(boot) you can do it like this
- i have this avd installed Pixel_5_API_30
- run this command and write the avd name in Capital letter  `emulator @PIXEL_5_API_30`
  you will get your booted avd ready
  cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use this command if you want a cold boot and still be able to save the emulator state when it exits: emulator **@emualtor_name -no-snapshot-load**

if you don't want to save the state when it exits use: **emulator @emulator_name -no-snapshot-save**

Otherwise, if you want to completely turn off the Quick Boot feature and ensure that the emulator does not load or save state then use this command:
emulator **@emulator_name -no-snapshot**